# Produce rotating effect with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to C++ and i want to ask how to solve the given below problem. I searched a lot but not get reasonable help.Threading library of c++ may help.How to use two threads to show two rotating bars at the two top corners of a screen. Basically each thread will be driving the “rotation” of the bar. (Hint: You can use “\” and “/” to achieve the effect but you will have to figure out how to achieve the effect of “rotation”.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem with multi-threading is that you need to properly synchronise the different threads, as they share a common resource (either console or GUI). Preferably you'd do the stuff within a single thread:

```
uint32_t timestampLeft = getTimestamp(); // get high precision timestamp, at least
                                         // ms (peak into <chrono> header for
                                         // writing this function yourself;
                                         // hint: make sure to use steady_clock!)
uint32_t timestampRight = getTimestamp();

for(;;)
{
    uint32_t timestamp = getTimestamp();
    if(timestampLeft - timestamp > PeriodLeft)
    {
        // exchange left symbol
        // update console or GUI
        timestampLeft = timestamp;
    }
    // right analogously
}
```

If you insist on threads (or are *required* to use):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

uint32_t constexpr PeriodLeft, PeriodRight; // TODO: initialize appropriately! 
bool isRunning = true;
std::mutex mutex;

void run(uint32_t index, uint32_t period)
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard g(mutex); // to avoid race conditions: lock the mutex

            // update character/image for specific index
            // redraw global/entire output

            // mutex gets unlocked automatically as soon as guard leaves scope
        }
        // sleep for period
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread left(run, 0, PeriodLeft);
    std::thread right(run, 1, PeriodRight);
    // find out if we need to stop, then set isRunning to false
    left.join();
    right.join(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tahnks for your help.